# How to accept a put request in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to build a survey app in rails 3. Basically I need to make a wa yi to accept responses from a set of questions. (surveys have many questions and responses.) I got it to render but when I submit it it sends as a put instead of a post. So is there any way I can add a custom put route to my response controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# routes.rb
put '/surveys/:id' => 'surveys#update'
```

Assumes `SurveysController` has method `update`.